# How to ask forgiveness for the bad words we use in our inner mind?

Tags: forgiveness

Today I saw a post in Facebook about a cancer patient who were asking for donations. I said, "he is showing off his sickness for popularity". Although I said this in my mind but I regretted after thinking about this things.Will Allah forgive me for this or will punish me and my close one's with such a desease?

Answer (score 2):

Salam 'alaykum

the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah will forgive my ummah (followers) for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not speak of it or act upon it.” Narrated by al-Bukhari, 4968; Muslim, 127

This does, however, not mean you should just deliberately have bad thoughts about other muslims all the time or even about Allah, as this would fall under Suu-u-ddhan (bad thoughts), there is a difference between waswaas (unintentional thoughts, suggestions from Shaytaan) and your own corrupt thinking/assumptions

Hope this answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Reading some other answers on this sub, I think those temporary unintentional thoughts are considered waswasah (whispers) from shaitan. Generally, I don't think we are responsible for the thoughts as along as they were unintentional and we regretted them as soon as possible.

Some advice:

- Ask forgiveness from Allah
- Pray for healing from Allah for the cancer victim as a way of mending your heart towards them and reversing negative thoughts
- Pray that Allah forgive the cancer victim's sins. That is a way I was taught of reversing negative thoughts about people.